# Why doesn't CAST work with SET ROWCOUNT?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm wondering why I can't use a CAST function as the parameter to SET ROWCOUNT in a Stored Procedure.

This code fails:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetTransactions
    @Count VARCHAR(5)
AS

    SET ROWCOUNT CAST(@Count AS INT);
...
```

While this code with an intermediary variable works:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetTransactions
    @Count VARCHAR(5)
AS
    Declare @Rows AS INT;
    SET @Rows = CAST(@Count AS INT);

    SET ROWCOUNT @Rows;
...
```

I know that changing the parameter type to INT would also fix this, but the middle-tier component that calls the Stored Procedure needs everything to be a String type.

Comment: simply because you can't! You have to use the intermediary variable. Why is that a big deal?

Comment: Haha!  Wow, I never would have thought it was that obvious!  I just want to make the code as simple as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in many cases with SQL Server's TSQL implementation, you cannot pass an expression to `SET ROWCOUNT`. The valid arguments to [SET ROWCOUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx) are either a number (constant) or a simple variable:

> ```
> SET ROWCOUNT { number | @number_var }
> ```
>
> number | @number_var
>
> Is the number, an integer, of rows to be processed before stopping the specific query.

The same applies to calling a stored procedure, in that you can't have expressions as parameters.